# Going through 2 other tables SQL

Tags: sql

I'm banging my head against a wall here.  Just started learning SQL, I have three tables like this:

Table CD (num, producer, band_name, cd_name)

Table BandSingers (band_name, singer_id)

Table Singer (id, name)

I'm trying to figure out how to get the name of the singer that shows up on the most Cds by going through the band, and I'm not sure how to go about it but here's what I've got:

```
select id, name
from Singer, BandSingers
where Singer.id = (select singer_id
                from BandSingers
                where band_name = (select band_name
                                    from CD
                                    where max(count(band_name))));
```

think I'm way off but help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please post which DBMS you are using. . . and delete your answer from below.

Comment: The tables seem strange. Obviously you are dealing with bands, singers, and CDs. There is a singer table and a CD table, but no band table, though. Your database deals with CDs only that contain one band. Okay. We know a band's singers may change after time, but your database doesn't consider this. Okay again. Then there is the BandSingers suggesting an n:m relation between bands and singers. But is this the case? Or is this a band table actually? Is `band_name` unique in `BandSingers`? When showing tables, please always tell us about unique keys in them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this dude

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.NAME
FROM SINGER s
JOIN BANDSINGERS bs ON s.singer_id = bs.singer_id
JOIN CD c ON c.BAND_NAME = bs.band_name
WHERE c.band_name = (SELECT band_name 
                    FROM (SELECT band_name,COUNT(band_name) cnt 
                    FROM CD 
                    GROUP BY band_name 
                    HAVING COUNT (band_name)=(SELECT MAX(mycount) 
                    FROM ( 
                    SELECT band_name, COUNT(band_name) mycount 
                    FROM CD 
                    GROUP BY band_name))))
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this instead

```
Select Top 1 c.id, c.[name], Count(a.band_name)

From CD a
left join BandSingers b on b.band_name = a.band_name
left join Singer c on c.id = b.singer_id

Group by c.id, c.[name]

Order by 3 desc
```

Answer (score -1):

figured it out, I manipulated the syntax to a 'group by' and 'having', and it worked out.

Comment: If you want to post a solution then post it. Don't tell us "there exists a solution". This is no valid answer.